# Ссылки на товар в Drupal (прайслист через views)

Tags: drupal, views

Реализовал краткое представление товара (прайслист) через views
Но там при создании\редактировании views'a даёт создать ссылку лишь на административную часть (на редактирование объекта).
А как сделать чтобы ссылка делалась\предлагалась на обычный просмотр?
см.скрин
[image: картинка-drupal]

Answer (score 1):

Судя по скрину, вы добавляете заголовок ревизии материала, а не заголовок самого материала.

Если вы выберете заголовок материала, то ссылка будет вести куда нужно.

Comment: Я понял вашу мысль, но увы, перепробовав все возможные варианты, ссылки почему-то ссылаются на административное управление товаром.